# Laravel/ MSSQL (AWS RDS) General error: 20018 Unicode data

Tags: php, sql-server, amazon-web-services, unicode, rds

I'm using SQL Server with a Laravel 5.4 Project but when i use `Laravel\Socialite` it returns me a an error in my handler.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier. [20018] (severity 16) [(null)] (SQL: select top 1 * from [social_logins] where [social_id] = 109095424026454018110 and [provider] = google)
```

Some answers on Google/StackOverflow say that i have to change `tds version` to `8.0` and `client charset` but i have my database in a RDS on Amazon Web Services and can't change it (me noob).

Answer (score 0):

the problem was using select * in the Laravel way.

```
$userRes = User::where('email', '=', $user->email)->first();
```

So i added select('column1','column1') like this

```
$userRes = User::select('id','email')->where('email', '=', $user->email)->first();
```

Then everything is working well.